# Show that $P \left(\bigcap\limits_i(C\setminus C_i)\right) \le \exp \left(- \sum\limits_i P(C_i)\right)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Let $C_1,C_2,\dots ,C_n$ denote subsets from sample space $C$. 
>   To show :
>   $$P \left(\bigcap\limits_i(C\setminus C_i)\right) \le \exp \left(- \sum\limits_i P(C_i)\right)$$

What I tried :
I was inclined towards using the inequality $1 - x < e^(-x)$.However that kept leading me to $\bigcup P(Ci) > \sum P(Ci)$ which is absurd (after reducing LHS to $1 - P(\bigcup Ci)$.
I don't know of any other way to introduce the exp sign !

Comment: @Dylan Edits are supposed to improve posts, not to make them impossible to understand. (N. F. Taussig, Shailesh: Why accept such edits?)

Comment: @OP The inequality cannot hold without some further hypothesis. Independence?

Comment: No..Independence is not stated.Is it necessary to establish the statement?

Comment: "Is it necessary to establish the statement?" Quote: "The inequality cannot hold without some further hypothesis."